# How to remove pre-installed apps from Xperia E?

Tags: bloatware, sony-xperia

I recently bought a Xperia E and since I am not a Facebook user I'd like to remove it from my phone. That also applies for Google+ and other stuff which is installed on my phone by default but I am realy not going to use it so it just consumes my memory and battery.

I tried to go for example to Settings->Apps->Google+ but there is only disable option, not unistall like with manually installed apps.

Comment: You might want to check the [bloatware tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info). Hint: Hovering your mouse over a tag reveals additional information. Behind the 'info' link there you often find additional details and first-aid, while 'faq' brings you to the most frequented (and almost ever most interesting/important) questions for the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it came pre-installed with your phone then its a system app. You cannot uninstall it (unless you have your phone rooted, which i think you don't have). Best option for you is to disable the app. In this case, the app won't run and won't consume any CPU or battery (if that's your problem). If you are concerned about storage space running out then this won't solve the storage problem.

Comment: Ok, so I have to root my phone in order to delete this applications completely?

Comment: Yes. Have you followed the link I gave in my comment on your question? All required information can be found there. And as for the term "memory" in Sumit's answer, please replace it with "storage" -- an app which was not started does not consume "memory" (RAM) but just storage :) Besides, as those apps are installed on `/system`, you won't gain much "storage" removing them (only that occupied by their data, which is stored below `/data`), as `/system` during normal operation is read-only.

Comment: @Izzy - I wrote my answer more than an year back and now when I read it I kept on wondering how could I write memory in place of storage/ROM :)

Anyways, I edited my answer.